# Get status based on other table column value mysql

Tags: mysql, status

I have two tables.
job_table.

```
job_id  job_type    job_type       User         job_time               job_name
1       1           Day            User1        2015-04-23 23:20:10   Job1
2       2           Night          User2        2015-04-23 13:20:10   Job2
3       3           Day & Night.   User3        2015-04-22 23:10:10   Job3
4       3           Day & Night.   User3        2015-04-20 13:40:10   Job4
5       1           Day            User4        2015-04-26 03:20:10   Job5
```

and task_entry table.

```
task_entry_id    job_id      task_option_type     emp_id        completed_task_count    status
1                1             Day                  101         10                      1 
2                1             Day                  102         0                       0           
3                1             Day                  103         5                       1 
4                2             Night                101         20                      1 
5                3             Day                  101         4                       1 
5                3             Night                101         0                       0 
6                3             Day                  102         10                      1 
7                3             Night                102         5                       1
```

If job_type of job_table is 3 then there will be 2 entries in task_entry table one for Day and one for Night.
Else only one entry.

That is if job_type is 3 then count should be count/2. (Day&Night).
Else count should be normal count.

I want to get the status based on the job_id. If all task_entry for a job_id is 1 then status should be 'COMPLETE' else 'PENDING'
and total completed_task_count.

```
job_id      task_entry_count    status      completed_task_count
1           3                   PENDING     15
2           1                   COMPLETE    20
3           2                   PENDING     19
```

How can i get that.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select job_id,count(task_entry_count),case when a.job_id is null then 'Compeletd' else 'pending'end as status,sum(completed_task_count)
from task_table
join (select job_id from task_table where status=0) a a.job_id =task_table.job_id
group by job_id
```

Comment: This is my query which works to get the task_entry_count. SELECT jt.job_id, ROUND(SUM (CASE WHEN jt.job_type = 3 THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END), 0) AS task_entry_count FROM job_table jt INNER JOIN task_entry te ON jt.job_id = te.job_id GROUP BY jt.job_id